Let $G$ be a simple graph such that $\chi(G) = k$ and $\chi(G\setminus\{v\}) < k$ hold for all $v \in G$. Show that $G$ is 2-connected
I've been attempting to solve the following problem but I'm stuck.
Let $G$ be a simple graph with at least 3 vertices such that $\chi(G) = k$ and $\chi(G\setminus\{v\}) < k$ hold for all $v \in G$.

Show that $\delta(G) \geq k -1$.

Show that $G$ is 2-connected.


I've been able to show 1. but not 2. I tried to prove it by contradiction and was able to show that $G$ cannot be disconnected but I'm unable to show that $G$ having a vertex cut leads to a contradiction.
Any help would be greatly appreceiated!

In this case, you could try and prove something a bit stronger. But first your question:
Suppose you have a cut vertex $v$ such that $G-v$ has at least two components $A,B$ with no edges going in between. Now you can color $A \cup \{v\}$ and $B \cup \{v\}$ with $k-1$-colorings $c$ and $c'$ respectively. And you may permute the colors in coloring $c$ such that $v$ gets the same color under both $c$ and $c'$ (i.e. $c(v)=c'(v)$). These two colorings now yield a proper $k-1$-coloring of $G$, a contradiction.
Now with this idea, what can you say about the following scenario: Say there is a clique in $G$, which separates the graph i.e. a clique cut?
I hope my answer helps you, and let me know if something is unclear or I made a mistake (:

why you can color $A \cup v$ using k-1 colors

Deleting a vertex in $B$, and coloring the resulting graph in $k-1$ colors induces a proper $k-1$ coloring on $A \cup { v}$
